# Changing the style of a component when different component renders in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using a lot of components combine together to make a UI of the website. As a newbie, I am not sure how can I change the `css/style` of the component when a new component renders. For example a component lets say **SearchBar** is on the component as the image below.

[image]

The SearchBar css makes it at the center of the page.

But when I click on the search button and the next component renders I want to change the css and take it to the top. Is this even doable?

Comment: Post your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes - very doable.  simplistically you need to have the change stored in state, in a parent  component .  you then use this state as a prop in the child you want a dependency on, when the state changes, the prop also changes causing your child component to re-render.  At this point you can change what ever you want to the render of you child, based on the new value of this prop in the child.